# Contatenating two date values into one column

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g, concatenation, to-char

Should be a pretty simple question.  I have two fields - one a year field and the other a month field.  The month field is an integer and if there is only one digit such as 6 for June there is no leading zero.  I want to concatenate the two fields together to get 201406 not 20146 if I concatenate them together now.  I tried 
`year||to_char(month,'09')` but the field is being displayed as 2014 06 with a space in-between the year and month.  Is there a way to do this without a space?

Comment: use `trim(year)||to_char(month,'09')` thats because your yaer field was saved with a space

Comment: Thanks Jorge, that should work but still displaying 2014 06 and the length is 7.  Any other suggestions?  I am using Oracle 11g is that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output contains a space, then either your year or your month column contains a space. To get rid of these, you can use `TRIM`:

```
with v_data(year, month) as (
  select '2015 ', ' 1' from dual union all
  select ' 2014 ', ' 12 ' from dual union all
  select '2014', '3' from dual
)
select trim(year) || lpad(trim(month), 2, '0') 
from v_data
```

(this assumes that you really have two string columns - if you indeed have two date columns, please add example input to your question)

**UPDATE**

If you want to use `to_char()` instead, you should use the [`FM` format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) to get rid of the space:

```
select trim(year) || trim(to_char(month, 'FM09')) 
from v_data
```

Comment: Thanks both answers worked.  For some reason I had to trim the formatted filed too...trim(year)||trim(to_char(month,'09'))

Comment: That's because without the `FM` modifier, many format models of to_char() add a leading blank, see the Oracle docs (link in my updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, by default, `to_char` leaves a space in front of a positive formatted number, so that they line up well with negative numbers. To prevent this, use `to_char(month,'fm09')`.